# ConcurrentModificationException -> How can I change my code to stop it from throwing this error?

Tags: java, exception

```
for (FPlayer p : fPlayer.getFaction().getOnline()) {
            p.setFaction(null);   
        }
```

Basically, the getOnline method returns an array list of the current FPlayers that are online. When the FPlayer is removed from their faction, the faction is set to null (p.setFaction(null)).

I cannot think about how to change my code to stop it from throwing the ConcurrentModificationException. I have used an iterator but still, it.next().setFaction(null) still throws the same exception.

EDIT:
USING A LIST ITERATOR:

```
    ListIterator<FPlayer> it = fPlayer.getFaction().getOnline().listIterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        it.next().setFaction(null);
    }
```

> Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

At the line

> it.next().setFaction(null)

EDIT #2:
Set faction method:

```
public void setFaction(Faction faction) {
    if (hasFaction()) {
        this.faction.getOnline().remove(this);
    }

    this.faction = faction;
    if (faction != null) {
        this.faction.getOnline().add(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Without seeing any code, and without seeing the stack trace of the exception, how could we possibly help?

Comment: Use ListIterator instead!

Comment: @JBNizet it is simply a ConcurrentModificationException from calling a method inside the bracket that edits the object p.

Comment: @vvtx used a list iterator with the same result.

Comment: What does setFaction do? Looks like it must be modifying the list you are iterating on. There are ways around it, but modifying something *while you're iterating on it* is usually a bad idea.

Comment: Yep - this is entirely dependent on what setFaction is actually doing. I wrote up a quick mock but I was unable to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because while iterating you are removing the data from the list .

Couple of solutions  .

1. If the list size is small convert it to array and then loop over
2. Use for loop for iteration .

   ```
    for(int i=0;i<fPlayer.getFaction().getOnline().size();i++)
     {
       // Condition to check if true 
          if(true)
             {
              fPlayer.getFaction().getOnline().remove(i);
               i--;
                 }
     }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, change your code so it doesn't change the collection inside the loop you are running. For example, create a copy of the collection before iterating.

```
for (Foo foo : new ArrayList(myFoos)) {
   if (foo.isBar()) {
       myFoos.remove(foo);
   }
}
```

Iterating and changing the list without the `new ArrayList()` would have caused a `ConcurrentModificationException`